# php associative array of objects

Tags: php, class, object, associative-array

I'm trying to create associative array of objects from row result set with member id as the key, but getting some error.

addATravelog() is just a function of the class UserLogsAndSOS(), whose objects i want in array.

Here is what I tried:

```
class UserArraySet {

private $arrayOfUsers = array();    

function createArrayForTravelogs($result) {
    While($row = $result->next()) {
        if(array_key_exists($row['id'], $this->arrayOfUsers)) {
            $this->arrayOfUsers[$row['id']] = new UserLogsAndSOS();
        }
    $this->arrayOfUsers[$row['id']]->addATravelog($row['title'], $row['blog']); //line     72                                           
    }
}
}
```

On calling createArrayForTravelogs() from the object I got the following error
Here is the error I got:

```
Notice: Undefined index: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\classes\userprofile.php on line 72

Fatal error: Call to a member function addATravelog() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\classes\userprofile.php on line 72
```

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this, I want something like this:

```
Array (

 [1] => objectUserLogsAndSOS1

 [5] => objectUserLogsAndSOS2
 ....
)
```

where key is the member id from $row.
I also need to check if the key exists, then call a function of that particular object to add data to its member, if not then create an object and then call a function of that particular object to add data to its member.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just read the error message: you only create UserLogsAndSOS if there is already an entry - otherwise you call addATravelog on null.
maybe you forgot the "!" in your if clause?

Comment: Oops! wasted whole day and googled it all day long.. Thanx Del

Comment: your welcome, please mark the question as resolved and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Because the array stays empty.

You only create a new `UserLogsAndSOS` when there already is an element with the provided ID in the `arrayOfUsers`. The exact opposite of what you probably wanted.

You're probably missing a `!` to reverse the `array_key_exist` result.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!array_key_exists($row['id'], $this->arrayOfUsers)) {
   $this->arrayOfUsers[$row['id']] = new UserLogsAndSOS();
}
```

> You missed and '!' I think this is causing the error